# Font Awesome 5 icon in stylesheet showing up with unicode

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm attempting to integrate FontAwesome like so:

```
.accordion:after {
 content: "\f0d7";
 color: #9E3E39;
 font-weight: bold;
 float: right;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-top: -80px;
 font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

and the end result is this:

[image]

`&#092;f0d7`

This is the script we're using for FA:

```
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
```

This is in a invisionfree based forum, using the bbcode [dohtml] to activate html coding.

What am I doing wrong? I feel like in theory it should be all good?

Comment: I don't know if font awesome works for pseudo selectors in the javascript version.

Comment: Yeah,  as far as I know, javascript has no access to pseudo selectors.

Comment: You could try using @font-face in your CSS to make sure that FontAwesome is included in your CSS.

Comment: @BrandonBaker the OP is using the javascript version which uses SVG's, not an icon font like classic Font Awesome does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the JavaScript version of FontAwesome supports pseudo-classes, they're **[not recommended](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#pseudo-elements)**:

[image]

As such, you should either use the CSS version:

```css
.accordion:after {
  content: "\f0d7";
  color: #9E3E39;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  /*margin-left: 5px;*/
  /*margin-top: -80px;*/
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="accordion">Accordion</div>
```

Or better yet, make use of the `<i>` tags (considering it as an `svg` target for additional styling):

```css
.accordion svg {
  color: #9E3E39;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">Accordion <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your `font-family` might be wrong. Please go [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js) and go to the "CSS Pseudo-elements" section and **read the warning**.

It looks like you need to set the `font-family` to `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Solid";`

You maybe also need to add this `script`

```
<script>
  FontAwesomeConfig = { searchPseudoElements: true };
</script>
```